# Unpack dictionary values into function arguments

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to unpack dictionary values and pass them into function arguments.
I have a 1D dictionary that might contain strings, integers and floats or all together as values.

In the example code Im using the latest case. The dictionary contains integers, floats and strings as values.

Example Dictionary

```py
my_dict = {'name': 'String VaLue', 'id': 1, 'price': 10.5 }
```

Example function:

```py
def exampleFunction(valueA, valueB, ValueC):
    # Do something
```

I have tried using the `values()` function to extract the values but I get a `float value` error.

Desired result:

```py
my_dict = {'name': 'String VaLue', 'id': 1, 'price': 10.5 }

# Dictionary value extraction

# Passing extracted values as function arguments
 result = exampleFunction('String VaLue', 1, 10.5)
```

Comment: `result = exampleFunction(*my_dict.values())`

Comment: i would like an explanation  please

Comment: `my_dict` has 2 "name" keys, the first will be overridden by the second.

Comment: messed up my copy paste. its an id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mydict.values()` is a sequence of all the values in the dictionary `mydict`.

In the context of a function call, `*foo` means "pass each item in sequence `foo` as a separate argument".

Putting these two concepts together, we get:

```
exampleFunction(*my_dict.values())
```

If you're getting a float error, that likely means that the float value is being passed as (say) the second item when you expected it to be the third.